# .net - dependentAssembly

Tags: .net, configuration

Today I was getting some assembly mismatch issue and after a bit of digging I found that for a particular DLL, actual reference in project was made to some other version and
config file for that project was showing dependency to some other version of the same DLL.

Exp.

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="NHibernate" publicKeyToken="aa95f207798dfdb4" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.0.1.4000" newVersion="2.1.2.4000" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

I removed the dependency declaration for that assembly from the config file and voila! I was able to run again :-)

My question is -

When are `<dependentAssembly>` declarations made in the project config file?  Do we add them manually? And in what scenario?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When are `<dependentAssembly>` declarations made in the project config
>   file? Do we add them manually? And in what scenario?

When you want to ensure the software binds to a newer version of an assembly at runtime than that which it was built against.

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19.aspx

> Can you please also guide in what scenario we need older version at
>   compile time and newer version at run-time?

For example, if you are using a vendor API, the vendor may have identified a bug and needs to issue a new version but you've already shipped.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Can you please also guide in what scenario we need older version at compile time and newer version at run-time?

Comment: For example if you are using a vendor API, the vendor may have identified a bug and needs to issue a new version but you've already shipped.